# Is there a way to detect redundant parentheses in OCaml code?

Tags: ocaml

I am interested in detecting redundant parentheses in `OCaml` code. Some ideas I have tried with no results include using regular expressions, comparing reverse code generated from AST. I am lost on how to proceed with this task.

Comment: find a pair of parentheses, remove it, does it compile to the same thing?

Comment: what is the end goal? ocamlformat more or less does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple solution. Parse the code (using compilerlibs) and then print it back (again using compiler libs) and compare the results. The compilerlibs pretty printer will not put any redundant parentheses. To make the comparison easier, you can remove all spaces, or just count the number of parentheses.

There are less heave and more adhocy approaches, e.g., to catch the common misuse of parentheses:

- `f(x)` instead of `f x`
- `(f x) * (f y)`, instead of `f x * f y` where `*` is an arbitrary infix operator.

Finally, the general approach, in case if you need for the student project. Would be to compare operators precedence and mark operators that have higher precedence (bind tighter) but still have parenthesis, e.g., `(x * y) + z`, here `*` has higher precedence than `+` but is still delimited with parentheses.